# htaccess rewrite rule to rewrite directory/name to index.php?id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using this code in my htaccess file:

```
# Rewrites /blog/post-name-1 to be /index.php?post_name=post-name-1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=blog&post_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

i want to rewrite `/blog/post-name-1` to look at `/index.php?id=blog&post_name=post-name-1`

but it is showing 404 Page Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need following:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrites /blog/post-name-2 to be /index.php?post_name=post-name-2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1&post_name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrites /blog/post-name-1 to be /index.php?post_name=post-name-1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=blog&post_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also ensure the following;

- You've allowed .htaccess to be the override file on httpd.conf
- You've set `AllowOverride` to `ALL` in httpd.conf